# Installing data science packages to vanilla python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

How to download necessary python packages for data analysis (e.g. pandas,scipy,numpy etc) and machine learning packages (sci-kit learn for starter, tensorflow for deeplearning if possible etc) without using github or anaconda?

Our client has permitted us to install python 3.6 and above (32-bit) in our terminals for data analysis and machine learning projects but we cannot access github due to security restrictions and also cannot download anaconda bundle.

Please provide suitable weblinks and instructions.

Comment: Download the binary wheel files from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and install with `pip`

Comment: Thanks for the link. Much appreciated !! Please suggest whether we have any specific dependency route to take or the packages would install the dependencies as we get them done in R. Sorry for such naïve question, a newbie to vanilla python. Have used anaconda and R before.

Comment: If you just used the command `pip install numpy` then it would install the dependencies too. I'm not sure if downloading the wheel files and using pip to install them will do the same. If you are able to do `pip install some_package` then I would recommend that as shown in an answer below.

Comment: @DavidG, After download from the site you suggested, the installation worked. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Install the packages using pip(Python package manager). 
Simply use the following "pip" command in the terminal and install them.
For an example, if you are installing the tensorflow package enter the following command in the terminal.

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Refer this URL for more instructions.
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

Comment: No, it doesn't work due to firewalls. Have to go via @DavidG  route as the installs need to be done using local directory.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by @DavidG, the following solution worked:

Download the whl file
use cmd window and go to the download folder and then install like below:

```
 
C:\Users\XXXXXXXX>cd C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Documents\Python Packages
C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Documents\Python Packages>pip install numpy-1.13.0+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
Processing c:\users\XXXXXXXX\documents\python packages\numpy-1.13.0+mkl-cp36-cp
36m-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.13.0
    Uninstalling numpy-1.13.0:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.13.0
Successfully installed numpy-1.13.0+mkl
```

C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Documents\Python Packages>pip install scipy-0.19.1-cp36-cp36m
-win32.whl
Processing c:\users\XXXXXXXX\documents\python packages\scipy-0.19.1-cp36-cp36m-
win32.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in c:\users\XXXXXXXX\appdata\local\
programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scipy==0.19.1)
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy-0.19.1

C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Documents\Python Packages>